# Windows 8.1 idle/auto maintenance runs on battery

Tags: laptop, battery, windows-8.1

Just recently upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8. I noticed that, when on battery, idle and auto maintenance tasks run regardless of the power situation. Curiously, I looked in task scheduler, and they both have "Start the task only if the PC is on AC power" OFF. I tried setting them back on, but they keep resetting. It really eats away at my battery, too, as I'm on a laptop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Device Manager for any unknown devices and also look for ACPI related drivers on your laptop manufacturers web site. It might be some missing or failing driver that stops Windows from finding out that it is running on battery Power.